# Angular CLI 1.6.7 "ng build" is failing with ERROR but no exit in Jenkins

Tags: angular, jenkins, angular-cli, exit

When running the following build command in the Jenkins shell-script:

`npx -p node@10.0.0 npm run deploy:closed`

`npx -p node@10.0.0 npm run deploy:open`

in the package.json:

`deploy:closed": "ng build --app closed --stats-json --prod --build-optimizer --locale nl"`

`deploy:open": "ng build --app open --stats-json --prod --build-optimizer --locale nl"`

If the first command gives an **ERROR**, then the script will continue to run and eventually returns a **SUCCESS** for the entire build. I expect Jenkins to return **FAILED** and stop building if the `ng build` fails.

Is there any configuration in the angular-cli that will `exit` the build correctly? It looks like it is exiting the script with `exit 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found.

When executing `ng build` with `--stats-json`, the build will always exit with code 0, even when the build fails.

To fix this, either remove `--stats-json` from the `ng build` command or check whether a `stats.json` file has been created after the build.